# What was this game I played with friends about 10 years ago

Tags: identify-this-game

I'd like to get some help identifying a game I played with some friends about 10-12 years ago but solely based on my rough memory. Any help is appreciated!

- The game was played on a pretty big "board" (think 100x50cm) made of hard-plastic hexagons
- The board was not rectangular but made of "modules" of those hexagons
- You also setup hills by stacking the hard-plastic hexagons
- Somehow, everybody got assigned playable characters together with a card describing the attack/defense (?) stats for every character
- You then fought with your available characters (some expendable soldiers, some high-value characters)
- I think I remember the types of characters as pretty diverse: I think there were guys with machine guns and some kinds of monsters

Unfortunately, this was before the age of smartphones and I do not have any pictures to help identifying the game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has a lot of similarity with Heroscape, details in favor for it:

1. Released 2004 until its discontinuation in November 2010
2. Modular layout with multiple Master Sets and Expansion Sets
3. Plastic hills and landscape
4. Multiple heros characters, troops and monsters

Image from Wikipedia

[image]